# Edittext and Tab Issue

Tags: android

In my application, I'm creating dynamic tabs.Inside framelayout I've created a edittext.For
each tab i create content of tab will be edittext. When i type in editext of one tab and later if i create a new tab  and when I switch between these tabs, it shows the content of editext as empty.

#### Update:

I don't want to create a separate activity for each tab.I'l explain along with the code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final TabHost tabs = (TabHost)this.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
      tabs.setup();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec1=tabs.newTabSpec(f);
   spec1.setContent(R.id.content1);
   spec1.setIndicator(f);
tabs.addTab(spec1);
tabs.setCurrentTab(i);
list.add(spec1);  
i++;
    Addbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) 
  {
          final TabHost tabs = (TabHost)this.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
      tabs.setup();
          TabHost.TabSpec spec1=tabs.newTabSpec(f);
     spec1.setContent(R.id.content1);
     spec1.setIndicator(f);
    tabs.addTab(spec1);
    tabs.setCurrentTab(i);
    list.add(spec1);  
    i++;
    });
```

Default one tab will be there. here content of tab is edittext. When i click on button new tab will be created. problem is with the content of tab. In default tab if i type in edittext, and create a new tab and switch to the default tab the content of default would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the value of the EditText in some manner. A good way is to show tab content through an activity and use [this method to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state) store instance state.

Comment: I tried created activity for each tabs. It was throwing exceptions.

Comment: I'm doing everything in the same activity. OnSaveInstanceState() method gets called when user leaves the activity.But I'm in same activity.

Comment: Paste the errors of your program (multiple activity mode). Have you registered the activities in the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an EditorActionListener, which is called when someone presses the 'Enter' or IME_ACTION key to store the values of your EditText.

Instead of doing *spec1.setContent(R.id.content1);*, create an EditText dynamically (new EditText(context)) and put a number (Tab Number) as a Tag, which you can retrieve and store in a List.

```
mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                KeyEvent event) {

                                       int position = (int) v.getTag();

                                       String s = ((EditText) v).getText()
                                       // store in an object

                      return false;
       }
});
```

Not sure how you will retrieve this without launching subActivities!

Comment: I'm facing one more problem.
I created a menu.
In menu option how can i access the current tab?